# VBA paste a block of cells at once

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to write VBA codes like below. However, it is taking forever to update each value as I pull value from "another_ws". Is there a faster way of doing so? The code is taking hours to run.

```
Dim another_ws as worksheet
Set another_ws = wb.sheets("sheet1") 

For row = 1 To 500
    For column = 1 To 500
        ws.cells(row, column).value = _ 
        ws.cells(row, column).value + another_ws.cells(row, column).value
        'another_ws comes from another workbook
    Next column
Next row
```

Comment: Consider using **Copy** and the **PasteSpecialAdd** on an entire block rather than cell-by-cell.

Comment: Can't test so I put it here `ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Value = ws.EVALUATE("INDEX(" & ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Address(1, 1) & " + " & another_ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Address(1, 1, xlA1, True) & ",)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use a loop:

```
Sub WhatEver()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:SF500")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:SF500")

    r2.Copy
    r1.PasteSpecial xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
End Sub
```

Comment: You actually counted out 500 columns? I was lazy and used resize.

Comment: @ScottCraner I cheated and MsgBox'ed `Cells(500,500).Address(0,0)`

Answer (score 4):

A couple of different methods:

WorkSheet.Evaluate:

```
Dim another_ws As Worksheet
Set another_ws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Value = ws.EVALUATE("INDEX(" & ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Address(1, 1) & _
    " + " & another_ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Address(1, 1, xlA1, True) & ",)")
```

Using arrays:

```
Dim another_ws As Worksheet
Set another_ws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")    
Dim oarr() As Variant
Dim tarr() As Variant

oarr = ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Value
tarr = another_ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Value

For i = 1 To 500
    For j = 1 To 500
        oarr(i, j) = oarr(i, j) + tarr(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Value = oarr
```

Or as @Gary's Student stated, PasteSpecial Add:

```
Dim another_ws As Worksheet
Set another_ws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")

another_ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).Copy
ws.Range("A1").Resize(500, 500).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
```

Comment: @user2864154 if you use the Pastespecial Add method make sure you mark Gary'sStudent's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Does your run flicker back and forth between ws and anther_ws?
This visual update can be taking computer cycles as screen draws each worksheet upon grabbing values.

You could try turning off updating at the beginning of your code and turn it back on at the end.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False